# row echelon vs reduced row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra

I apologize if this is a very basic question.

I understand the difference between the two forms, but i was curious when row echelon from is enough. where is row echelon form used?. Why shouldn't I always go for reduced row echelon form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to lessening the workload involved in computing a *determinant* of a square matrix, e.g.,

- one can confirm or rule out whether a square matrix is invertible by stopping before full reduced row-echelon form,
- we can determine the rank of a matrix without needing to go through the tedious work sometimes involved in obtaining full reduced form row-echelon form, and
- we can determine whether the row or column vectors of a matrix are linearly dependent or independent with just plain old row-echelon form.

Certainly, each form has its uses, and the fact that we can sometimes avoid extensive and tedious computations (which also leave room for introducing simple errors along the way), that's  **not** to say that it is *not* important to know how and when to obtain reduced row echelon form: but we can "pick-and-choose" to some extent "how far" we need to row-reduce.

Comment: Nicely dramatized Amy.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer.
Seems like its mostly about not doing extra work?

Comment: Absolutely: that's about it. There's really no circumstance where one *must* stop short of full reduced echelon form. So use what you're most comfortable with.

Comment: @amWhy: nice feedback + 1

Answer (score 2):

One example: if using row operations to simplify the calculation of a determinant.  It is just as easy to compute the determinant of an upper triangular matrix as to compute the determinant of a diagonal matrix; so, there is no reason to go all the way through to RREF.

Comment: Thankyou sir. I marked Amy's answer as accepted since its more extensive.