# Calculating the rank of a matrix , reduced row echelon or row echelon?

Tags: matrices

I am trying to calculate the rank of a matrix and everytime I search for the steps required to calculate the rank of a matrix, the answer always uses the terms **row echelon form** and **reduced row echelon form** interchangeably when calculating the rank which is really confusing.

I have read this question [row echelon vs reduced row echelon form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440071/row-echelon-vs-reduced-row-echelon-form) in which the given answer says that we use row echelon form instead of reduced row echelon form (as it's a tedious process) to calculate the rank however one the answers from a paper my university gave me had this written on it:

```
Alternatively the rank is obtained by counting number of non-all-zero
rows in reduced matrix form above.
As:
rank of A + nullity of A = dimension of A
```

It seems to me now that it doesn't really matter which form I use? Is there a difference between using row echelon form to calculate the rank and reduced row echelon form to calculate the rank of a matrix? I'm really confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Row echelon form is simply a matrix such that all nonzero rows are above rows of all zereos, and the leading coefficient is a nonzero row is strictly to the right of the leading coefficient of the row above it.

Reduced row echelon form *is* a **matrix that is in row echelon** form but adds the condition that the leading coefficient is the only nonzero element in a column.

It may be tedious to go from row echelon form to reduced row echelon form but there are equivalent by a finite number of steps.  Thus since they are equivalently matrix then the rank of the matrix must be the same.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I was looking for.